What exactly does one mean by a "vacuum sector" in a Hilbert space?
I was going through a rather unique but interesting paper (arXiv) by Chiribella on an extension of Quantun Shannon theory to include even quantum trajectories.
In his paper, when a system corresponds to a subspace of a larger Hilbert space, it is referred to as a sector. In an attempt to define what it means to have a superposition of channels in a resource-theoretic sense, he introduces the concept of a vacuum extension of a quantum channel. This was motivated by the argument that the physical apparatus used to communicate doesn't come into existence at the moment when it's used to transmit a signal - like an optical fibre that exists even when no photons are sent (so when this optical fibre isn't used, one can model it as taking vacuum as an input). Noting this, he assumes that the system used to communicate is a sector $A$ of a larger system $S$, and this contains another sector, called the vacuum sector $Vac$, which is ALWAYS orthogonal to $A$. This orthogonality essentially tells one that it is always possible to perfectly distinguish between sending something and sending nothing (when we consider the system $S = A \oplus Vac$ as this represents a quantum system that can be in sector $A$, or in sector $Vac$, or a coherent superposition of the two).
Assuming that the vacuum sector is one-dimensional, he defines that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a quantum channel and $\mathcal{\tilde{C}}$ is its vacuum extension, then given $\{\tilde{C_i}\}_i$ and $\{C_i\}_i$ are Kraus operators for $\mathcal{\tilde{C}}$ and $\mathcal{C}$, respectively, then $\tilde{C_i} = C_i \oplus \gamma_i \vert vac \rangle \langle vac \vert$ where $\vert vac \rangle$ is a unique vacuum state up to global phases (which makes sense as the sector is 1D), $\gamma_i$ are called vacuum amplitudes of $\mathcal{\tilde{C}}$ and $\sum_i |\gamma_i| = 1$. Note that vacuum being one-dimensional is an assumption, and one can also (as the authors claim) formulate vacuum dynamics in arbitrary dimensions (further work has been done in the paper's Appendix).
Although he claims all these are inspired by the concept of vacuum in quantum optics, I'm unable to conceptualise what a vacuum means in the first quantisation of quantum mechanics (whereas the concept of vacuum makes sense to me when we work with Fock spaces). What types of states are present in this 'vacuum' sector? What even are these "vacuum amplitudes"? What do all of these precisely mean when it comes to experiments? All these would've made sense had we been dealing with Fock space, but that's not the case here.
